# Activity has leaked window in onClick method

Tags: android, progressdialog

I've read many same questions but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I just want to show the dialog when my query is going on (to show loading process).
When I press the button "Ok" it executes SQL query and dialog window must be shown, but it don't.
Here is my code:

```
 public OnClickListener btnOkListener = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        eWord = etWord.getText().toString();

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btnOk:
                syns.clear();
                lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
                dialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Please wait");
                dialog.setMessage("Loading");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Dialog is showing");
                dialog.show();


                String query = // SQL query


                Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

                int wordColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SynDB.Word);
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    string_word = cursor.getString(wordColIndex);
                    syns.add(string_word);


                }
                displayListView();

                lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
                cursor.close();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog dies");
                dialog.hide();

                break;
```

and my LogCat log:

```
05-19 09:51:50.238    1865-1865/com.psdevteam.SynoDict.app D/MyLogs:﹕ Dialog is showing
05-19 09:51:50.248    1865-1865/com.psdevteam.SynoDict.app D/MyLogs:﹕ Dialog is died
05-19 09:51:51.738    1865-1865/com.psdevteam.SynoDict.app W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ No keyboard for id 65539
05-19 09:51:51.738    1865-1865/com.psdevteam.SynoDict.app W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-19 09:51:54.888    1865-1865/com.psdevteam.SynoDict.app E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.psdevteam.SynoDict.app.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@b5d2ba98 that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.psdevteam.SynoDict.app.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@b5d2ba98 that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:259)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
        at com.psdevteam.SynoDict.app.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:93)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9081)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Use `asyncTask` for this, show your dialog in `onPreExecute` , do your job in `doInBackground` and dismiss your dialog in `onPostExecute`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan could you show how to make doInBackground method in this case? whit my code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following code, but be careful, you can't update your view in `doInBackground` so if you want change your UI you need use one of followng method:

```
 onPreExecute
 onPostExecute
 publishProgress
```

publishProgress is used for update UI while doing your job in `doInBackground`

```
  private class GettingData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Please wait");
            dialog.setMessage("Loading");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Dialog is showing");
            dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String query = // SQL query


            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

            int wordColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SynDB.Word);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                string_word = cursor.getString(wordColIndex);
                syns.add(string_word);
            }

        return null;
    }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                displayListView();

                lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
                cursor.close();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog dies");

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
}
```

Comment: sorry, an application works perfect! and it also do what I want, thank you so much!